# YA book about paper mâché dragons coming to life

Tags: story-identification, dragons

i remember reading a young adult book about a teen in modern times (1980-1990) who makes a bunch of paper mâché dragons as a hobby and they end up coming to life and attacking him in his home.   I have no idea the title or author  but I recollect the cover drawn as the main protagonist in a chair as the dragons come find the stairs behind him.  Any help!?   I have scoured the Internet for l the last 5 years on and off with no luck.

Comment: Are you certain it's dragons? I remember something very similar involving them being gargoyles. They had an electronic chip in them to give them limited speech, he'd added some fur to them, and their eyes could glow. He wanted to sell them as toys, but hadn't found a buyer due to their grotesqueness. The cover did show all three of them moving down the stairs as he sat there. Unfortunately, the name escapes me if it is that one.

Comment: I have this vague image in my head, but I haven't found the book yet. I want to say that it was a one-word title, the name he wanted to give to his creations. I only made it a few chapters in. There were at least three of the "bag guy" ones and I think one that was more benign. I remember reading a bit of it and getting Gremlin vibes off of it.

Comment: Aw man... this one is like on the tip of my brain!

Comment: As per our current criteria, we don't close duplicates for being good matches unless there's indication of acceptance.

Answer (score 3):

Per user45049's [answer to a similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/87663/20774), could this be [**Dragon Fall**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0380884682), by Lee J. Hindle?

It's described in an [off-site question](https://www.jacketflap.com/megablog/?blogid=213&reload=yes&page=214) as being

> ....about a young boy who made dragon statues (papier-mache or maybe 
>   clay) and they came to life to attack him, etc. Of course the grown-ups 
>   don't believe him, etc.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Valorum. I should have thought to add an answer. I don't think Dan is coming back, though...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - No worries. Since I closed it, it only seems right for me to make the effort to actually answer it.