# Book from the '80s, first person prose, modern timeframe, something with dragons and Sammy Hagar music

Tags: story-identification, novel

There was a book I read in high school (the '80s) that I remember enjoying, but can't remember many details. The most prominent things I remember are that it was published because the author won an award (young adult writers award or something?). I also remember the music the main character was listening to at one point, "Three Lock Box" by Sammy Hagar. Does anyone know the title?

Edit - The cover had a male teenager and dragons on it.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Your question has been marked as a duplicate because it has been answered already. :) It's still a good question, and this is no censure on you. You will still get all past and future upvotes on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be *[Dragon Fall](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3527161-dragon-fall)* by Lee J. Hindle as per [Book about a would-be toy designer being stalked by his creations](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/82014/23243)

> "It started late one saturday night after he got home from a rock concert. Something grabbed him from behind. Something wanted to hurt him. Then the voices began. Threatening. Warning. Vicious. At first he thought it was his imagination. Gabe had an excellent imagination. He used it to design monsters. Five-foot-tall, red eyed, jagged toothed monsters. The kind that sold to toy stores for big money. But Gabe isn't thinking about money right now. Because a night alone is turning into a night of terror. He is looking at the worst nightmare his mind ever imagined. And they're coming to tear his flesh...Now...Right now!

[Hindle got his chance to publish the book by winning a contest run by Avon/Flare](https://books.google.com/books?id=cWYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false), the monster toys are described as "dragons" at times, and the cover does show the boy and his monsters.

[image: Front cover of Dragon Fall]

The book can be [borrowed from the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/dragonfall00hind/mode/2up). Unfortunately, a quick browse through it doesn't reveal any references to Sammy Hagar or "Three Lock Box", although there is a scene (shortly before the toys attack) where he falls asleep listening to Billy Squier singing "[Lonely Is the Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonely_Is_the_Night)" (titled "How Lonely Is the Night" in the text). Also not matching, now that I've reread a bit, is that it's third-person, not first-person. But a lot of other bits match. :) This might yet still be your book.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! :)

Comment: :) Glad I could help. As you might see if you follow the link, I was searching for it myself, as have several others.