# '70s/'80s young adult supernatural horror novel set in the real world where sculpted goblin models come to life

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, horror

I have a vague memory of a young adult supernatural horror novel from the '70s or '80s in which a late high school/early college-aged male is a sculptor/toymaker and three of his creations, a trio of goblin-esque brothers, come to life and engage in mayhem. It just occurred to me that their names may be a riff on the Three Musketeers, specifically D'Artagnan, Athos, and Porthos.

I feel like the writing was very atmospheric and the narrative shifts between the toymaker's POV and the goblins' (the latter of whom are mostly static statues throughout the novel) with something like telepathic communication between the goblins but not much physical movement until maybe near the end. If I recall correctly, the climax of the story involves the dollmaker burning his house down in an attempt to stop the goblins.

Comment: You're sure it's d'Artagnan and not Aramis?  d'Artagnan was kind of the fourth musketeer...

Comment: Hmm...those three names were the most resonant when the concept occurred to me just now (w/ an impression that D'Artagnan was the lead goblin) but it's definitely possible Aramis was in there instead of D'artagnan. That said, my memory of the book is pretty patchy and I'm not totally positive any of the Musketeers names were even used - it could've been another trio or some sort of riff/set of nicknames rather than the exact names.

Comment: Your question has been marked as a duplicate. Note that this is not a censure, or an indication that this is a bad question. It is merely one that we have had asked before, and we like to link them together in the system. You will still get points for upvotes to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Book about a would-be toy designer being stalked by his creations](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82014/book-about-a-would-be-toy-designer-being-stalked-by-his-creations/87702#87702), this may be *[Dragon Fall](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3527161-dragon-fall)* by Lee J. Hindle.

[image: Front cover of Dragon Fall]

> "It started late one saturday night after he got home from a rock concert. Something grabbed him from behind. Something wanted to hurt him. Then the voices began. Threatening. Warning. Vicious. At first he thought it was his imagination. Gabe had an excellent imagination. He used it to design monsters. Five-foot-tall, red eyed, jagged toothed monsters. The kind that sold to toy stores for big money. But Gabe isn't thinking about money right now. Because a night alone is turning into a night of terror. He is looking at the worst nightmare his mind ever imagined. And they're coming to tear his flesh...Now...Right now!

However, the names of The Dragons Three that stalk him are Hubub, Sid, and York according to the [Internet Archive copy of the book](https://archive.org/details/dragonfall00hind)