# Paper mache dragons that come to life

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, dragons

Looking for a young adult book I read in my high school library in Toronto, Ontario, Canada, back in the early 1990's about a teenager who makes three dragons out of paper mache, and they come to life and attack him.

I have looked all over and cannot find out anything else about this book, author unknown, title unknown.

Comment: Probably the same book as here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80185/ya-book-about-paper-m%C3%A2ch%C3%A9-dragons-coming-to-life

Answer (score 4):

The book you are looking for may be [*Dragon Fall,*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0380884682) by Lee J. Hindle. Written in 1984. Loved this book when I was a kid.

[image: cover of "Dragon Fall" by Lee J. Hindle]

From the back cover:

> It started late one Saturday night after he got home from a rock
>   concert. Something grabbed him from behind. Something that wanted to
>   hurt him.
>  Then the voices began. Threatening. Warning.
>   Vicious.
>  At first he thought it was his imagination. Gabe had an
>   excellent imagination. He used it to design monsters. Five-foot-tall,
>   red-eyed, jagged-toothed monsters. The kind that sold to toy stores
>   for big money.
>  But Gabe isn't thinking about money right now.
>   Because a night alone is turning into a night of terror. He is looking
>   at the worst nightmare his mind ever imagined. And they're coming to
>   tear his flesh.
>  Now... Right now!

Comment: Could you flesh this answer out a bit? Why do you think this is the right story? Do you have a plot summary or something?

Comment: Hah. Probably also the answer for http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82014/book-about-a-would-be-toy-designer-being-stalked-by-his-creations and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80185/ya-book-about-paper-m%C3%A2ch%C3%A9-dragons-coming-to-life

Comment: I can confirm that it's the right answer for the first. I recognize the cover. Post it there and I can accept the answer.